# Why the DOM parser won't display all the data from XML file?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, domparser

I'm learning how to write parsers in Java, now I'm trying to make a DOM XML Parser, but my parser doesn't display all the data from my XML file. What's the problem? Can somebody help me?

Here's the class for DOM Parser:

```
    public class DOMParser2 {
    private static Shoes getShoes(Node node) {
        Shoes shoes = new Shoes();
        if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            Element element = (Element) node;
            shoes.setTitle(getTagValue("ss:title", element));
            shoes.setBrand(Brand.fromValue(getTagValue("ss:brand", element)));
            shoes.setCategory(Category.fromValue(getTagValue("ss:category", element)));
            shoes.setSeason(Season.fromValue(getTagValue("ss:season", element)));
            shoes.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(getTagValue("ss:price", element)));
        }
        return shoes;
    }
    private static String getTagValue(String tag, Element element){
        NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node node = (Node) nodeList.item(0);
        return node.getNodeValue();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String filepath = "ShoesShop.xml";
        File xmlFile = new File(filepath);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(xmlFile);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.print("Root element: " + document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            
            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("ss:ShoesShop");
            
            List<Shoes> shoesList = new ArrayList<Shoes>();
            for(int i = 0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++){
                shoesList.add(getShoes(nodeList.item(i)));
            }
            
            for (Shoes shoes:shoesList){
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(shoes.toString());
            } 
        } catch(Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As a result I get this:

> Root element: ss:ShoesShop [title=Baltrum, brand=GUCCI,
> category=BOOTS, season=FALL, price=734.0]

Here's an XML-file

```
    <ss:ShoesShop xmlns:ss="http://www.example.org/ShoesShop" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/ShoesShop ShoesShop.xsd ">
      <ss:shoes id="1" stock="true">
        <ss:title>Baltrum</ss:title>
        <ss:brand>Gucci</ss:brand>
        <ss:category>Boots</ss:category>
        <ss:season>fall</ss:season>
        <ss:price>734.0</ss:price>
      </ss:shoes>
  <ss:shoes id="2" stock="true" mostWanted = "true">
    <ss:title>Amalfi</ss:title>
    <ss:brand>Dior</ss:brand>
    <ss:category>Mules</ss:category>
    <ss:season>winter</ss:season>
    <ss:price>364.0</ss:price>
  </ss:shoes>
</ss:ShoesShop>
```

Comment: Your first println reveals the answer.  Your root element is not named `ShoesShop`, and it does not have any descendant elements named `shoes`.

Comment: VGR, thank you, it helped. But I can't display a full list. How can I change that?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("shoes");` returns an empty list.  Perhaps you should try the actual tag name, `"ss:shoes"`?

Comment: I tried "ss:shoes" it didn't help. When I tried "ss:ShoesShop" it returned only the the first note from the XML-file (actually, it has 5). When I change item value there, for example: NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(1).getChildNodes(); it displays the second note, when item(2) it displays the third note etc. 
I need to display all of them.

Comment: Edit your question and show the actual code you are running.

Comment: I've updated my question, you can look at a full code

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("ss:ShoesShop")` returns a NodeList with only one item in it, because there is only one `<ss:ShoesShop>` element in your XML document.  Perhaps you wanted a list of `<ss:shoes>` elements?

Comment: Yes, I want a list of <ss:shoes> elements, but it doesn't work

Comment: “it doesn’t work” is not a problem statement anyone can address.  Describe what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: I've found my mistake, I've been using <ss:Shoes> and got an error when I should've using <ss:shoes>. Thank you so much for help and wasted time to explain me that.